# nginx keeps answering with the 'default nginx site' despite it being removed from config

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, web-hosting

I was hoping someone could help me with this strange problem.  On a 'clean' server install, I have the following "website.com" and nginx configs, yet if you try to go to the `http` version of `www.website.com`, it renders the *default* nginx page, instead of forwarding over to the `https` version like it's configured to do.  The site is using the AWS Linux ami, and is behind an elb (hence the directive for elb-check).

In my `/sites-available` (and `ln -s`'d to `/sites-enabled`), all I have (even when doing a `# ls -lah`) is:
`default_server  website.com  elb-check`

The configs (as well as the `nginx.conf` are below).

Thank you in advance!  Please let me know if there's additional info/configs you need.

website.com:

```
# Send http www. to https www.
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.website.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.website.com$request_uri;
    server_tokens off;

    }

# Send http non www. to https www.
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.website.com$request_uri;
    server_tokens off;

    }

# Send https non www. to https www. 
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.website.com$request_uri;
    server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate "/path.to.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/path.to.key";
        ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    }

# Answer https and www. requests

    server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name www.website.com;
        index   index.html index.php;
        root    /home/website/html;
        access_log  /var/log/website/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/website/error.log;
    server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate "/path.to.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/path.to.key";
        ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        root    /home/website/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        }

    location ~ /private\.php$ {
        auth_basic "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/website/.htpasswd;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
```

nginx.conf:

```
# nginx config
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # Load Virtual Sites
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;

    index   index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_tokens off;
}
```

default_server:

```
# To black-hole all other subdomain requests
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

elb-check:

```
# So the ELB sees the instance as still being alive
server {
    location /home/elb-check { 
    access_log off;
    return 200;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run `nginx -t` and check the output carefully.

Comment: this is what I do all the time @Mic

Answer (score 6):

Nginx will choose the first server in the config if no default server is specifically defined. Install a dummy default server.

```
# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't know which
# server block to send a request to
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 444;
  access_log off; log_not_found off;
}
```

You may want to define a default https server as well, though it will probably generate certificate warnings if it's not on a specific domain. I don't bother.

Comment: Why is mine routing to the _default_ nginx page though?  There's nothing directing traffic to that location (`/usr/share/nginx/html`).

Comment: Probably because it's a default built into nginx, and your higher up sites don't define a root.

Comment: How Nginx knows what is the "first server in the config" ? Good one...

Comment: @prosti that's the point. The order of servers is undefined (at least to me) so you use the default_server directive to tell Nginx what to do, rather than effectively letting it choose randomly. I'm sure there is an order that files are included, perhaps alphabetic, but I don't know it and it's not important enough to look up.

Comment: first of all to get the idea of "first server in the config" you would need to check the algo fo the nginx. I sure this is based on the `include` directives order you specify in nginx.conf, else if you have a wild char it may be even based on OS call. Like you set ls *.conf, but not important as you said. nothing big, just that sintagma of yours brought my attention.

Answer (score 2):

I think another issue is/was with the nginx.conf, at the bottom where you are including the sites-enabled/*. You are including both available and enabled configurations. You are loading your configuration twice, so nginx, not finding a working config, will always default to a basic config.

```
# Load Virtual Sites
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*; <-- do not need this too.
```